# Mongoose find search if statement error using expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is a URL shorten-er project

```
app.get('/:url', (req,res) => {
Url.find({userUrl:req.params.url},(err,doc)=>{ //finds if there is a link in the database
    if(err){
        console.error(err)
    }else if(doc[0].userUrl==req.params.url) {  // there is an error in this line if a new link is passed in the params.url, or else if the link existed then there is  no issue 
        console.log('hi')
    }else  {                     // if no link is not reaching?
        const url = new Url({
            userUrl:req.params.url
        })
        url.save();
    }

})
```

})

if i have a link in my database example google.com , it does give me output of hi , but when i put other link it gives me a 'property userUrl undefined' error in the first else if statement.

my schema is like this `let urlsSchema = new Schema({
    userUrl:String,
    shortUrl: {
        type: String,
        'default': shortid.generate
    }
})`const Url = mongoose.model('urls',urlsSchema);`

i think i need to write it in a way where, if you cant find it in the database then create a new url document.. not working tho
`

Comment: Check `if(doc[0])` or `if(doc.length)` before accessing it. The returned document list might be empty (if no results were found)

Comment: @JonasW. it worked!! i added doc.length && in the first if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `find` only throws an error if either the request is corrupted or the database connection does not work. If no data was found, it will not return an error but rather an empty `doc` array. If you then access `doc[0]`, it will return undefined, and undefined has no `userUrl`. A possible solution would be to check if the doc array has a first document:

```
Url.find({ userUrl: req.params.url }, (err, doc) => {
   if(err){
    return console.error(err);
   if(doc[0]){
    //Exists already
    console.log(doc[0]);
   } else { 
    //Doesnt exist yet, so create a new one:
    const url = new Url({
        userUrl: req.params.url
    })
    url.save();
  } 
});
```

Note that you should rather use `findOne` to check for existence.